# Add authentication to Carrot2 WAR file

Tags: solr, carrot2, carrot

Is there any way to add basic authentication to Solr using the Carrot2 WAR file?

We used to run Carrot2 with a local solr instance, but now we are moving it to another VM that will work exclusively on Solr.

I have set the URL on the source-solr-attributes.xml just like that:

`<attribute key="SolrDocumentSource.serviceUrlBase">
   <value type="java.lang.String"
     value="http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/select?wt=xml"/>
</attribute>`

Since there is no java code on the version that we're using, how/where can I set an user and login to make sure Carrot will use it to communicate with Solr?

Comment: Have you tried the `http://username:password@localhost:8983/solr/mycore/select?wt=xml` syntax?

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh I forgot to mention that my Solr is protected by HTTPS basic authentication (username/password). I have tried to simulate the request in that way but it didnt work 

https://username:password@myip:8983/solr/mycore/select?